# Selecting images and displaying titles in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React functional component that has a list of images with titles:

```
export function MyComponent() {
  const images = [
    { image: "http://www.example1.com/image1.jpg", title: "Title 1"},
    { image: "http://www.example2.com/image2.jpg", title: "Title 2"},
    { image: "http://www.example3.com/image3.jpg", title: "Title 3"}
  ]

  const [titles, setTitles] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <div>

      <div>{titles}</div>

      <section className="images">{
        images.map(image => (
          <img
            src={image.image}
            alt={image.title}
            onClick={() => {}} // selects or unselects the image?
          />
          )
        )}</section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click on an image, I want it to be either selected or unselected. When it is selected, I want a CSS border to appear. If an image is selected, I want the list of selected image titles to appear in `<div>{titles}</div>`. I was thinking of using `React.useState()` here, but I am not sure how to do it. I do not want to refactor to use a class; it must be a functional component. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to select one image at a time and display the title of it. So, here is a naive approach that you can adapt according to your situation.

```js
const images = [
  { image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150", title: "Title 1" },
  { image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150", title: "Title 2" },
  { image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150", title: "Title 3" },
];

function Main() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{images[selected] && images[selected].title}</div>

      <section className="images">
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <img
            className={index === selected ? "selected" : ""}
            key={`${index}${image.title}`}
            src={image.image}
            alt={image.title}
            onClick={() => setSelected(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

So, you have one state, the selected `index`. For the `className` part you look for the image's `index`, compare with the `selected` state then assign a class name according to that. For the title part, you are just grabbing the `title` by using the selected `index` with a conditional JSX.

But, using indices is not reliable. It would be better to have some unique ids for the images.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function MyComponent() {
  const images = [
    {
      image: 'http://www.example1.com/image1.jpg',
      title: 'Title 1',
    },
    {
      image: 'http://www.example2.com/image2.jpg',
      title: 'Title 2',
    },
    {
      image: 'http://www.example3.com/image3.jpg',
      title: 'Title 3',
    },
  ];

  const [titles, setTitles] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{titles}</div>

      <section className="images">
        {images.map((image) => (
          <img
            style={{
              border: titles.includes(image.title) ? '3px solid black' : 'none',
            }}
            src={image.image}
            alt={image.title}
            onClick={() => {
              if (titles.includes(image.title)) {
                setTitles(titles.filter((title) => title !== image.title));
              } else setTitles([...titles, image.title]);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```